# Unable to create powershell script to run DNN scheduled task on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, dotnetnuke

I am trying to run a powershell script on an azure machine to update the scheduler of a DNN task.

The below compiles fine however when I run it I get the error

Exception calling "RunSchedulex" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

There is no arguments it should be taking. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to work. (or if i am even going about the entire problem the right way?)

Thank you

```
    $Assem = (
    "System.Net, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    "System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "DotNetNuke, Version=8.0.3.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
)

    $Source = @” 
    using System;
    using DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace DNNSchedule
    {
        public class Schedulex
        {   
            public static void RunSchedulex()
            {
                string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();         
                SchedulingProvider scheduler = SchedulingProvider.Instance();
                ScheduleItem general = scheduler.GetSchedule("Revindex.Business.Revindex.Revindex.Storefront.GeneralScheduler,Revindex.Business.Revindex.Revindex.Storefront", hostname);
                scheduler.RunScheduleItemNow(general);          
            }
        }
    }
    “@ 

    Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 

    [DNNSchedule.Schedulex]::RunSchedulex()
```

Comment: Did you try making an instance of object either by a constructor or new-object and then running the method on that? Maybe something like $schedx = New-Object DNNSchedule.Schedulex

Comment: Hi @BenH I did not. i am still new at PS coding. where abouts would i put that.

Comment: After the Add-Type, then replace the [DNNSchedule.Schedulex]::RunSchedulex() with $schedx.RunSchedulex().

Comment: Tried doing that but now it is saying that the method doesn't exist at all

        Method invocation failed because [DNNSchedule.Schedulex] does         not contain a method named 'RunSchedulex'.
        At D:\schedule.ps1:32 char:1
        + $schedx.RunSchedulex()
        + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound